# For some $\epsilon>0$, is there a $\delta>0$ such that $|(a,0)|<\epsilon$ for $|a|<\delta$?

Tags: vector-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $V$ and $W$ be normed vector spaces and suppose we also have some norm on $V\times W$. Is it possible to prove that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|(a,0)|<\epsilon$ for all $a\in V$ with $|a|<\delta$?

In other words:
Is the function $v\in V\mapsto(v,0)\in V\times W$ continuous in $0$?

I couldn't find a proof (without assuming a finite dimensional vector space), although I felt like this had to be true. Are there any **counterexamples**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it will not be continuous because if $V$ is infinite dimensional you can define two non-equivalent norms on $V$.

Assume $V$ is an infinite dimensional vector space, on which there exist  be two non-equivalent norms, say, $\|\cdot\|_a,\|\cdot\|_b$. Given any normed space $(W,\|\cdot\|)$, we can look at $V\times W$ equipped with the norm $|(v,w)|=\|v\|_b+\|w\|$. Since $\|\cdot\|_a,\|\cdot\|_b$ are not equivalent, we can find a sequence $v_n\in V$ such that $\|v_n\|_a\to 0$ but $\|v_n\|_b\not\to 0$.

For example, the sequence $(\frac{1}{n},\dots,\frac{1}{n},0,0,\dots)$ with only the $n$ first coordinates non-zero, tends to zero in the $\ell_{\infty}$ norm,
but does not tend to zero in the $\ell_1$ norm.